# Correct use of Angular TypeScript constructor - Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: angular, typescript

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
  /* useFactory: () => new MyService(MyAnotherService.myInteger) */
})
export class MyService{

  constructor(private someInteger?: number) {
    // doThings with someInteger
  }
```

--aot build will complain that `Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for...`

In fact, due to the `useFactory: ()` part, we are still able to run our application correctly. But I do not know if this is the right way or not

We can, of course, change the constructor to

```
constructor(private anotherService?: MyAnotherService) {
        // doThings with anotherService
      }
```

To shut the build warning, 
However I do not think that `MyService` should be dependent on `MyAnotherService` when It can be just dependent on a primitive, It's also bad for code reusability

What is the best thing to do in this situation?

*My idea is that. Angular use Decorator to instruct that it is an Angular component ( am I right? )
So the main logic body should not always be coupled to Angular DI logic, especially if It is a service. We can pull the service code and plug it elsewhere ( Using DI or not )*

Comment: why are you passing 'private someInteger?: number'

Comment: That is one of the configuration I would like to have available at the construction phase, just that. Is that not normal in Typescript to have that kind of constructor?

Comment: Constructor should generally be used just for Dependency Injection

Comment: Do you require this service to be declared as a _tree-shakable_ provider?

Comment: How do you create an instance of that service? Do you always let angular DI do it? So how do you provide the integer parameter?

Comment: @David I added the edit to clarify why I would like to have the service created with or without the relationship to Angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an optional injection token

**token.ts**

```
import {InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';

export const INTEGER_TOKEN= new InjectionToken<number>('IntegerToken');
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {INTEGER_TOKEN} from './token';

@NgModule({
//...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: INTEGER_TOKEN,
      useValue: 1 //Or factory if you need one
    },
```

**service.ts**

```
import {INTEGER_TOKEN} from './token';

import {Injectable, Inject, Optional} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',

})
export class MyService{

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(INTEGER_TOKEN) private someInteger?: number) {
    // doThings with someInteger
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The common practice is to put so little logic in it as possible.
Most of the time the constructor is used to inject dependencies.

```
constructor(private anotherService: AnotherService) {
    // **don't** do Things with anotherService
  }
```

and then use it in another functions

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.anotherService.getValue().subscribe((value) => {
      // do something
   });
}
```

The function ngOnInit() will be called when the DOM from the component was created, all dependencies was injected and all inputs was binded. It's common practice to use the ngOnInit() even if the logic doesn't depend on DOM, input binding or Dependencie injection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these:

1. When facing issues that works in dev's `ng serve` but not in [AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler), turn on `"strictMetadataEmit" : true` to get details on what's wrong.
2. For example, AOT does not work with arrow functions.
3. Use `@Optional()` for [optional dependencies](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional).

Answer (score 0):

just remove the '?'

```
import {MyAnotherService} from '/pathto your service';
     constructor(private anotherService: MyAnotherService) {
           //prodedures
          }
```

or for the params:

```
myVariable: any;
constructor(private anotherService: MyAnotherService) {

this.myVariable = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Constructor should generally be used just for Dependency Injection**

```
 <my-component [state]="'joining'"></my-component>

    export class MyService{
  state: string;
      constructor() { 
        console.log(this.state) // => undefined
      }
      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.state) // => 'joining'
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can see in this case, I am trying to construct a service, @ Input decorator is to be used with @ Component only. Am I right?

Comment: can send --->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027711/angular-input-and-output-vs-injectable-service

Comment: ucan use it like model or variable