# How to send data from app.component to other (child) components

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular-components

I am using angular 6. I want to send data (which I am getting from external API) from app.component to other (child) components, I do not want to call that common API/Service in all components separately and repetitively. I want to call it once, so that's why I am calling in app.component.ts

Here is a service/API code

```
this.mainService.getBaseModel().subscribe(ret => {
        this.basemodel = ret;
    }, error => { }, () => {
});
```

I want to send this 'basemodel' value across all components in my app. Help me to resolve and understand it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to achieve this,

1. [**`@Input`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Input), with this we can pass the data to every `child component` from `parent component`.
2. **Create a common Service** for all these and then use service methods to get the Object

If you have one or two to components to share data from Parent then use @`Input` otherwise Service with latest **RxJs classes**([**`BehaviourSubject`**](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject), `Subject`, etc..) could be really easy.

if you want to follow @Input then follow this post - [pass @input data to child](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027711/angular-input-and-output-vs-injectable-service)

follow this for Service with BehaviourSubject - https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of you app it's hard to say which approach to use. 
You could use:

- combinations of `@Input()` and `@Output()`
- another service to save and distribute the data
- a store like ngrx

Answer (score 0):

In official Angular documentation you can find several approaches to this. They can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

There are also live examples for the above methods here:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/plpgkjondrl