# How to get data in component better?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

Using service inside component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.layer = this.layerService.getObject(semantic);
}
```

Or using `@Input()` and pass data from parent:

```
@Input() layers: any[] = [];
```

Should component control DOM, for example show/hide DOM elements, or everythin should be in services?

Something there a lot of data and I am confused to use a lot of Inputs()

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027711/angular-input-and-output-vs-injectable-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services should handle all the logical controls of your applications. The component should be a reusable element that use to show/manipulate DOM. In this case, what you are doing is correct. Service is passing the data and through the component, you are manipulating them to show on dom.

One other way you can do is using a `get` property to fetch the `layerService.getObject(semantic);` so that every time service change it logic, the component also gets updated.

```
public layers(): any[] {
  return this.layerService.getObject(semantic);
}
```

Comment: So, Inputs uses when I pass configuration to component? And services when I use data (praparing)? Lets assume we have varaible show in component. Sometimes it is  true/false. If it controls components it means only component knows last varaible statement. But sometimes I need open component with previous last changes.

Comment: @OPV if the variable is only used within the component then declare it here. But it's shared between multiple component then handle it through a service

Comment: @alessandro IMO It's more of general practice. Yes, you can use logic in your component but when your application gets bigger then code starts to duplicate and it can get messy easily. Services allow us to share the logic between components without any headache.